# How to retrieve data from Firebase using DialogFlow Inline Editor

Tags: javascript, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am pretty new to DialogFlow. I am wondering how can I retrieve data from Firebase  through the Inline Editor of DialogFlow. Hope you can help me!

Comment: In general - you'd do it just like you do it for any other Firebase Cloud Function. If you're having problems, updating your question to show your code for what you've tried and what errors you're getting would let us help you a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

Thats how you can communicate with firebase from dialogflow

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin');
const DialogflowApp = require('actions-on-google').DialogflowApp;
```

Initialize Firebase Admin SDK.

```
firebaseAdmin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

Interaction with firebase Collection `users` in fulfillment function

```
let userId = app.getUser().userId;
admin.firestore().collection('users').where('userId', '==', userId).limit(1).get()
.then(snapshot => {
      let user = snapshot.docs[0]
        if (!user) {
          // If user is not in DB, its their first time, Welcome them!
          app.ask('Welcome to my app for the first time!');
          // Add the user to DB
          firebaseAdmin.firestore().collection('users').add({
            userId: userId
          }).then(ref => {
              console.log('Added document with ID: ', ref.id);
          });
        } else {
          // User in DB
          app.ask('Welcome back!')
        }    
      });
  }

  // Map function hanlder to Dialogflow's welcome intent action 'input.welcome'
  const actionMap = new Map('input.welcome', start)
  app.handleRequest(actionMap);
```